# Grab a session value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I use the code line below in a javascript function to get a textbox value. Is there anyway to grab a session value instead. So like replace LastNameTextBox.ClientID with Session("LastName") etc.?

```
var LastNameTextBox = document.getElementById('<%= LastNameTextBox.ClientID %>');
```

Then I use the following to add it to a pdf.

```
   printWindow.document.write('Last Name:');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be exactly the same but with `Session("LastName")` instead of `LastNameTextBox.ClientID`), e.g.:

```
printWindow.document.write('Last Name: <%= Session("LastName") %>');
```

...although you may want to make sure the name is escaped correctly, since names can contain `'` characters (amongst other things), which if unescaped would cause an error in the script when it went to the client browser, because the browser would see:

```
printWindow.document.write('Last Name: O'Toole');
// Syntax error -------------------------^
```

If you're using .Net 3.5 or later, you can use [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to do the escaping for you.